# how to create .doc file using java?

Tags: java, apache, duplicates, apache-poi, .doc

Can anyone tell me how to create doc files using java?
I know, there's a POI library, but it seems like it can save only simple documents. You can read anything you wish, but you can't save it all back again. Or may be i missed something? How can i save whole document with pictures, tables and styles?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203174/whats-a-good-java-api-for-creating-word-documents

Answer (score 1):

[Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) lets you do heaps of styling easily via the template.  Uses OpenOffice and Java to do the job.  Its free and free to distribute.

Answer (score 0):

It ain't cheap, but you could try [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/file-format-components/aspose.words-for-.net-and-java/default.aspx). It'll do everything you state above and more.

Answer (score 0):

[JODConverter](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter) will allow you to convert lots of different document formats

Answer (score 0):

OpenOffice.org's Universal Network Objects (UNO),  allow you to generate *.doc,*.PDF,  as well as OpenOffice documents. It supports several programming languages like: Java, C++, Visual Basic, etcc..

Some good things is that: its free, open source and plataform-independent

You can build documents, spreadsheets, presentations, etc. Start from scratch or using a template and fill the gaps..

In order to use it you will need to include some libraries that comes with the OpenOffice suite.

Useful links:

- [Open Office home](http://www.openoffice.org)
- [Open Office UNO Developer's Guide](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/OpenOffice.org_Developers_Guide)