# How can I use Jacob to create a graph in a MS Word document

Tags: java, ms-word, histogram, jacob

How can I use Jacob to create a graph in a MS Word document?

Comment: This is an English speaking/writing website, please edit your question and use English language.

Comment: Google translation: How to use javacob to the operation of a histogram

Comment: Needs still more (understandable) explanation ..

Comment: "How to use javacob to the operation of a histogram?" as Google translated it from chinese

Comment: I don't see how this has anything to do with jacob

Comment: My take on it is: "How can I use Jacob to create a graph in a MS Word document?".

Comment: @Dumb Guy: Being a COM bridge for Java, Jacob could be useful to write Word graphs.

Comment: Maybe we need: "Belongs on cnprog" as a close option ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the answers for [What's a good Java API for creating Word documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203174/whats-a-good-java-api-for-creating-word-documents) can get you started.

Also, if English is a real problem, have you tried [cnprog](http://cnprog.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

Jacob was created by Dan Adler, so it may be worth looking at his website and FAQs -

http://danadler.com/jacob/

http://danadler.com/jacob/jacobfaq.html

And at the project hub on SourceForge

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/

There is a forum specific to Jacob on the SourceForge page, although there are no exact matches for creating a Word graph using Jacob.