# Desktop Application for Document Generator from Word Template (keeping photos, writing information to documents)

Tags: java, database-design, ms-word, desktop-application

I want to develop a `Java desktop application`. This appliation will `generate word documents` about patients. There will be some fixed and variable fields, columns at some templates.

System will be like that: I will keep the patients information(these are variables) There will be some messages, question at different templates(fixed variables) Patients will answer the questions and they will be stored too. After patients answer questions, give their information, appliation will `generate form/s`(this forms has fixed alignments, borders etc.) Patients will give their photos too and they will be stored at database.

System users will be able to `print` it and will have an ability to `search` documents, user, etc..

I will ask you how to develop that application, I mean how to `keep templates`, `write the information to the form` at correct places, organise a better `database`, organise photos etc.

I am open for other advises too about developing program(database side, Java desktop application side, better gui advices etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really see what your question has to do with database design. If you will be creating Word documents using the client application on the desktop the data should probably be available from there (at least during creation of the Word document). That the data is also stored on the server is not relevant (for the Word document).

There is already a question about [Word and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991030/word-document-creation-api-in-java), so you could read that for some information.

If however you decide to generate your Word (POI, via OpenOffice, COM interface) you will probably want to get the template, images and other data from the server to the client computer just before creating the Word file (and delete it afterwards), or let the server create the Word file.

As an alternative I suggest you look at the RTF format. Rich Text Format is supported by Word, can have images, and is more easy to handle (Java has a [Standard RTF editor kit](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/rtf/RTFEditorKit.html) included, I don't know how good it is).

Comment: It doesn't answer how to make a template but gives answer to java-word processes so how to do it manually.

Comment: @kamaci A Word template is a normal Word document made in Word.  You can add placeholders in the Word document and replace that text using POI (or another method).