# How to programatically insert image into Word document?

Tags: java

I am just looking for that. Is it possible to insert image into MS Word document through Java?
please reply....

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.util.Units;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();
        XWPFParagraph p = doc.createParagraph();
        XWPFRun xwpfRun = p.createRun();
        String[] IMageargs={
                "c:/1.jpg","c:/2.jpg","c:/3.jpg","c:/4.jpg"
        };
        for (String imgFile : IMageargs) {
            int format=XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG;
            xwpfRun.setText(imgFile);
            xwpfRun.addBreak();
            xwpfRun.addPicture (new FileInputStream(imgFile), format, imgFile, Units.toEMU(200), Units.toEMU(200)); // 200x200 pixels
            //xwpfRun.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE);
        }
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\test.docx");
        doc.write(out);
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Put the file in the link  [java file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B71tBf8F0DjNZFlmaUhBbHRWMUE/edit?usp=sharing) in the  path[src folder] and remember not to change the package structure.
I have tested it with word 2007, apache poi 3.10 not sure about other versions.

Answer (score 1):

Not easily, but it's possible. Try [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to [Openoffice UNO](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/OpenOffice.org_Developers_Guide) or [Aspose.word](http://www.aspose.com/categories/java-components/aspose.words-for-java/default.aspx) for JAVA.

More information on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203174/whats-a-good-java-api-for-creating-word-documents) old SO question.

[Here](http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=24160&p=110236&hilit=image+images#p110236) an example posted in Java section of Openoffice UNO forum.

[Here](http://api.openoffice.org/docs/java/ref/overview-summary.html) the Java Sdk.

Comment: not getting any thingh in Openoffice. please provide the exact source code for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Aspose Words for Java.

- http://www.aspose.com/categories/java-components/aspose.words-for-java/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to look at Apache POI HWPF - Java API to Handle Microsoft Word Files

http://poi.apache.org/hwpf/index.html

From the website:

> HWPF is the name of our port of the
> Microsoft Word 97(-2007) file format
> to pure Java. It does not support the
> new Word 2007 .docx file format, which
> is not OLE2 based.

This might be a good start:
https://github.com/apache/poi/blob/trunk/poi-scratchpad/src/test/java/org/apache/poi/hwpf/TestHWPFPictures.java

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straight forward with [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) - place a marker image, book mark it and tell docmosis to process the document replacing the image.

Answer (score 0):

If the document doesn't exist and you want to create from scratch, use this:

http://code.google.com/p/java2word

else: Apache PIO