# What API can add checkbox to MS Word file using Java?

Tags: java, api, ms-word

I wanna make a program to create MS Word file, but some API's can't add checkbox to the document. Someone have done that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about open office's api?

http://api.openoffice.org/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/form/FormComponentType.html

Also, see this Stackoverflow thread:
[What's a good Java API for creating Word documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203174/whats-a-good-java-api-for-creating-word-documents)

Comment: Ok, Thanks, if some Open Office's API can add checkbox, I'm going to use that.

Answer (score 0):

Apache POI may help you out... http://poi.apache.org/

Although, My experience with this API has been with excel and it appears the Word stuff is less developed.  Hope it helps though!

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. Have you added checkbox to the MS Excel file? Anyway, I'll check it out.

Comment: My experience here has been with Excel files however I did notice their section discussing Word so i thought I would at least mention it to you.  Sorry for not knowing more about its abilities with M$ Word docs.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [JODReports](http://jodreports.sourceforge.net/) or [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com).  Both sit over open office and can simplify some of the interactions with OpenOffice.  OpenOffice does a pretty impressive job of doc reading/writing and format conversions.