# Reading form checkbox values from a Word document using java

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I have a word document with checkboxes in it, and I want to determine whether these are ticked or not and use these results with java. I have tried using a WordExtractor with Apache POI but it didn't seem to include the result.

If I save the docx in txt format it replaces each checkbox with a corresponding 0 or 1, which is ideal, but I don't know how to do that programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

**Seems that you are looking for FtCblsSubRecord class (I didn't try it):**
http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/record/FtCblsSubRecord.html

http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/record/class-use/SubRecord.html

**Results of search in google:** checkbox site:poi.apache.org

=========================================

*By this post seems not to be posible:*
http://osdir.com/ml/user-poi.apache.org/2010-10/msg00068.html

*Other post talking about this:*
[What API can add checkbox to MS Word file using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407711/what-api-can-add-checkbox-to-ms-word-file-using-java)

[Insert a checkbox in an Excel sheet using Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15243438/insert-a-checkbox-in-an-excel-sheet-using-apache-poi)

Comment: The link to *FtCblsSubRecord* is misleading since this only applies to HSSF (aka Excel). For HWPF (Word; binary *.doc) see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34692292/5717099).