# couldn't get/set checkbox value in Word document (.doc) with Apache POI

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I'm trying to get/set checkbox value in Word document (.doc) with Apache POI.

I looked **HWPFDocument** API at **poi.apache.org**, but haven't found anything suitable...
Maybe somebody have a solution?

Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is currently not supported by POI. What does work is to read out (not set) dropdown lists via [`CharacterRun.getDropDownListValues()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hwpf/usermodel/CharacterRun.html#getDropDownListValues%28%29) and [`CharacterRun.getDropDownListDefaultItemIndex()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hwpf/usermodel/CharacterRun.html#getDropDownListDefaultItemIndex%28%29).

Technically those dropdown lists are closely related to checkboxes, though. So it should not be too difficult to add the respective functionality to POI, if desired. Your entry point is a [NilPICFAndBinData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd923826%28v=office.12%29.aspx) structure (handled by [this class](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hwpf/model/NilPICFAndBinData.html) in POI), which leads you to some [FFData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd906422%28v=office.12%29.aspx) (maps to [this class](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hwpf/model/FFData.html) in POI). Inside that you will find [FFDataBits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd921630%28v=office.12%29.aspx). These eventually contain an `iRes` value which encodes the status of that checkbox.
- This is exactly the same behavior as for dropdown lists, only that the `iType` of FFDataBits will be *iTypeChck* instead of *iTypeDrop* and has to be interpreted in a slightly different way.

Comment: How do we retrieve this NilPICFAndBinData from CharacterRun object, could you post a code example?

Comment: @teejay In the same way the two existing methods for dropdown lists already do it. I.e. look into POI's source.

Comment: OK found that quite easily (in source of CharacterRun.getDropDownListValues()). Now do you have any idea how to do similar task for newer .docx format? FFData is still there in xml but Apache POI doesn't seem to have a proper class for XWPFDocument. Thanks for ur input.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Had to write a **VBA macro** that gets the value of the checkboxs, stores it in a portable database and I get it from there.