# MS Word recognizing Heading/Font etc?

Tags: java, php, ruby, ms-word

I want to read a MS word document and Identify Header/Bold font words/Underscored words, etc? is there a way to solve this problem programmatically? I want the suggestion in Java or PHP or Ruby if possible, else if there is some meta-data available also let me know.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188452/reading-writing-a-ms-word-file-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have java API that can do that. I suggest you to look at the [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) library.

Comment: Apache Tika is a good project, I found out it does lot of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to this
[What's a good Java API for creating Word documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203174/whats-a-good-java-api-for-creating-word-documents)

There is a work in progress API for this one using Apache POI.

> HWPF is the name of our port of the
>   Microsoft Word 97(-2007) file format
>   to pure Java. It also provides limited
>   read only support for the older Word 6
>   and Word 95 file formats.and Word 95 file formats.
>
> The partner to HWPF for the new Word
>   2007 .docx format is XWPF. Whilst HWPF
>   and XWPF provide similar features,
>   there is not a common interface across
>   the two of them at this time.

http://poi.apache.org/hwpf/quick-guide.html