# Java Jsp - Can we save the output in a PDF or Word file?

Tags: java, jsp

I need to calculate few values and finally have to save it in a PDF or Word file.

Can we do that ?

We will have one button called 'Calculate & Save in a File'. Once the button is pressed we have to calculate and save it in a PDF or word file.

Is that a possibility? I do not need to display the output(not compulsory)...

Answer (score 1):

Yes for PDF you can use [JasperReport](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports), [iText](http://www.itextpdf.com/) , check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203174/whats-a-good-java-api-for-creating-word-documents) for word document

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just let the button trigger a servlet that uses iText or Apache POI to create the pdf of Word document, set the servlet output content type to the right value (e.g application/msword or application/pdf) and output the generated document.

Answer (score 0):

do your mean save output at server side or client ? i remember IE or firefox core has a component can render the page to a picture , i think it's maybe has someway to other format.    if on the server side , you can call POI interface to write context to pdf directly

but your should manly the pages layout, i think