# Android - creating word document

Tags: android, ms-word, apache-poi

I want to create `word`(.doc) and `excel`(.xls) files on the android platform.
For excel I am able to use `jexel` jar, but I am unable to find any API for word files.
Can you tell me if there are any opensource/free API for writing word files on the android platform?

People have suggested `Apache-POI` but I am not able to implement it in android. Please let me know if `Apache-POI` really works on android or not.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this thread, its java generally but it should also work on android platform [What's a good Java API for creating Word documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203174/whats-a-good-java-api-for-creating-word-documents)