# How can i read MS-Word bookmark from java

Tags: java

How can i read **bookmark of MS-Word** from **Java** application?

Comment: [What Have You Tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: In .net i was using Word.ApplicationClass, but i am new to java and don't know what to do.

Comment: *"i am new to java and don't know what to do."*  Are you new to search engines as well?  Try searching on 'read MSWord java'.

Comment: Maybe you can use OpenOffice UNO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203174/whats-a-good-java-api-for-creating-word-documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [POI project](http://poi.apache.org/) classes