# Dynamically create a MS Word report using a JIRA charts?

Tags: excel, ms-word, jira

Each month I have to manually create a report for my team.  For this I use a combination of numbers generated from a groovy script I've written, screenshot, cut & paste from a series of charts in our JIRA instance and cut and pasted excel charts.

I'm finding it more and more boring to do this by hand and I suspect that there is an easier way to automatically generate this report.  I can generate the word document with data from the groovy script using this application (http://www.docmosis.com/) but I have not yet found a way of auto including JIRA charts in the generation or excel so my question is:

Is it possible to generate a word document that contains generated data from various sources including (in order of importance):

- JIRA charts
- Programmatically generate data and
- Excel charts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the charts generated in Jira are created from data returned from search results. So you can get data from Jira using REST or SOAP api and generate your own charts by other means.

I am not sure if there is a no-coding method of doing it. But I would write a C# program that adds data to the Word template from your sources (Jira, other programs, Excel). And would create a template that generated charts from inserted data.

For Word document generation I would have a look here -http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20287/Generating-Word-Reports-Documents

For chart creation in the document I would have a look here - http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/create-a-chart-in-a-document-HP005190046.aspx

Comment: mmm, was hoping there was a method that didn't use hard work :>

Answer (score 4):

As you already coded your logic in Groovy, best would be skipping the Excel step and **generate your report directly from JIRA using the JIRA PDF View Plugin**. This plugin will reduce your work to a single click and download you a nice PDF document (PDF is more portable than Word docs).

These short tutorials help you:

1. [Reuse your Groovy scripts for reporting logic](http://midori.hu/products/jira-pdf-view-plugin/documentation/) (also see the "Charts" tutorial there)
2. [Bring the data, charts and the template together](http://midori.hu/products/jira-pdf-view-plugin/documentation/template-development)

*Update 2 years after my original answer:*

**JIRA PDF View Plugin 3.5.0+ can also export JIRA charts** (gadgets in JIRA dashboards, to be precise). So, now you can execute your Groovy scripts, include JIRA charts and bring all the result together in a professional PDF document.

Even better, now there exists a free plugin that will make the monthly process 100% automatic for you! It will generate your PDF document and send that to your team members' mailboxes, according to the preferred schedule (CRON trigger).

Related tutorials:

1. [Exporting JIRA dashboards to PDF](http://www.midori-global.com/products/jira-pdf-view-plugin/documentation/dashboards)
2. [Automating JIRA PDF exports](http://www.midori-global.com/products/jira-pdf-view-plugin/documentation/automation)

Discl: I'm a developer working on these products, yet this is the best solution to your problem. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest if you convert your JIRA chart to an image first.  When you say JIRA chart, do you mean something from [this plugin](https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/svn/JCHART/trunk/)?

Once you have an image, your document generation tool ought to be able to include that.

There are many document generation tools which can include programmatically generated data, and some of those can include Excel charts.

Comment: no, just the charts that are part of the normal JIRA installation (from the gadgets page). You can get to them via a link.  What are the tools that you reference here?

Comment: There are too many to list, and questions of that sort seem to get closed here.  Google is your friend; qualify your search with your preferred programming language.

Comment: See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203174/whats-a-good-java-api-for-creating-word-documents but this is by no means comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a JIRA plugin to generate charts in Word documents which may help you.
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.clariostechnology.officecharts.officecharts

Comment: Nice! Expensive though. My monthly report is not that important. I've fallen back to generating the text I need with s groovy script using the jira rest api and manually copying in the charts.

Answer (score 0):

There is now also Intelligent Reporter for JIRA which is a no-code method for creating word documents from your JIRA data, including native Word charts with full formatting from JIRA data.

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.clariostechnology.intelligentreports

Disclaimer: I work for the company that created this plugin.  If there is anything you need that it cannot do, please let me know.