# Add image to doc file

Tags: java, image, text, doc

I am trying to implement a requirement from client. The main thing is the client will provide me an image, I have to resize it and add it to a doc file. Then he wan to add a custom text 'on' the image[text wrapping in front of the image]. I need to do it with java. Can anyone suggest me which library will help me to implement this requirement? i have gone through  [docx4j](http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j).

Any small suggestion will be much helpful.

Comment: I got something from SO itself
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203174/whats-a-good-java-api-for-creating-word-documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) is a Java library for working with Microsoft documents, including `.doc` files.