# How to avoid java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, apache-poi, noclassdeffounderror, doc

I have a code for adding the texts to existing .doc file and it'll save that as another name by using apache POI.

The following is the code I have tried so far

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.model.XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFFooter;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTable;

public class FooterTableWriting {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String path="D:\\vignesh\\AgileDocTemplate.doc";
        String attch="D:\\Attach.doc";
        String comment="good";
        String stat="ready";
        String coaddr="xyz";
        String cmail="abc@gmail.com";
        String sub="comp";
        String title="Globematics";
        String cat="General";
        setFooter(path, attch, comment, stat, coaddr, cmail, sub, title, cat);
    }
    private static  void setFooter(String docTemplatePath,String attachmentPath,String comments,String status,String coAddress,String coEmail,String subject,String title,String catagory)
    {
          try{

                    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(docTemplatePath));
                    XWPFDocument document=new XWPFDocument(input);
                    XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy headerPolicy =new XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy(document);
                    XWPFFooter footer = headerPolicy.getDefaultFooter();
                    XWPFTable[] table = footer.getTables();

                    for (XWPFTable xwpfTable : table)
                       {
                           xwpfTable.getRow(1).getCell(0).setText(comments);
                           xwpfTable.getRow(1).getCell(1).setText(status);
                           xwpfTable.getRow(1).getCell(2).setText(coAddress);
                           xwpfTable.getRow(1).getCell(3).setText(coEmail);
                           xwpfTable.getRow(1).getCell(4).setText(subject);
                           xwpfTable.getRow(1).getCell(5).setText(title);
                           xwpfTable.getRow(1).getCell(6).setText(catagory);

                       }

                  File f=new File (attachmentPath.substring(0,attachmentPath.lastIndexOf('\\')));

                  if(!f.exists())
                      f.mkdirs();

                  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(attachmentPath));
                  document.write(out);
                  out.close();

                  System.out.println("Attachment Created!");

         }
          catch(Exception e)
          {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

    }

}
```

The following is what I got

```
    org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: The document is not a document@http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main: document element mismatch got themeManager@http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.onDocumentRead(XWPFDocument.java:124)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:200)
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.<init>(XWPFDocument.java:74)
    at ext.gt.checkOut.FooterTableWriting.setFooter(FooterTableWriting.java:32)
    at ext.gt.checkOut.FooterTableWriting.main(FooterTableWriting.java:25)
Caused by: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: The document is not a document@http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main: document element mismatch got themeManager@http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.verifyDocumentType(Locale.java:458)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.autoTypeDocument(Locale.java:363)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1279)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1263)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderBase.parse(SchemaTypeLoaderBase.java:345)
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.DocumentDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.onDocumentRead(XWPFDocument.java:92)
    ... 4 more
```

I have added all the jar files corresponding to this but still I can't find the solution.I'm new to this apache poi so please help me with some explanations and examples.
Thanks

Comment: Looks like you need `poi-ooxml-schemas.jar` that comes in the Apache POI distribution. Just adding a single jar doesn't mean that you have all the classes of the framework.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse?

Comment: yes....I'm using eclipse

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I have added that poi-ooxml-schemas.jar but now I got different error.I'll update my new error

Comment: How to avoid it? As usual, make sure, all required classes are on the classpath ;)

Comment: I'm using open office document.Will it be a supported type??

Comment: There is no `NoClassDefFoundError` in this question. Unclear what you're asking. Downvote.

Comment: lol @EJP if you actually read the comments the op said that he fixed the first thing by adding an extra jar and now he's getting a different error. Then he said he'd update the error. I wish I could downvote your comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copied from my comment done to the question:

Looks like you need poi-ooxml-schemas.jar that comes in the Apache POI distribution. Just adding a single jar doesn't mean that you have all the classes of the framework.

---

After solving the problem based on my comment (or another people answers), you have this new Exception

```
org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: The document is not a document@http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main: document element mismatch got themeManager@http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main
```

Reading [Apache POI - HWPF - Java API to Handle Microsoft Word Files](http://poi.apache.org/hwpf/index.html), it looks like you're using the wrong class to handle 2003- word documents: *HWPF is the name of our port of the Microsoft Word 97(-2007) file format to pure Java* ... *The partner to HWPF for the new Word 2007 .docx format is XWPF.*. This means that you need `HWPFDocument` class to handle the document or change your document from Word 2003- to Word 2007+.

IMO I find Apache POI as a good solution to handling Excel files, but I would look another options to handling Word documents. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/203174/1065197) to get more related info.

Answer (score 5):

This is the dependency hierarchy for `poi-ooxml-3.9.jar`.

[image]

Which means any of them can be used at *runtime* even if they aren't used at compile-time.

Make sure you have all the jars in the classpath of your project.

Comment: I have the following structure.But I have poi-ooxml 3.8 and poi-ooxml-schemas 3.8

Comment: Having different versions should not cause any issue.

Answer (score 3):

**Add this dependency on your config file:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

or

```
System couldn’t find the
```

> poi-ooxml-schemas-xx.xx.jar

**Please add the library to your classpath.**

Answer (score 0):

The class `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.DocumentDocument.Factory`  is located in the jar ooxml-schemas-1.0.jar which can be downloaded [here](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/apache/poi/ooxml-schemas/1.0/ooxml-schemas-1.0.jar)

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because you don't have the proper dependency for the XWPFDocument.  ooxml-schemas requires xmlbeans, and ooxml requires poi and ooxml-schemas, etc...

Check here: http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would report my experience with this error. I started getting it out of the blue, and hadn't changed anything in my workspace. Turns out that it occurs while trying to read an Excel file that has more than 1 sheet (second sheet was a pivot table, large amount of data. Not quit sure if it's due to the size of the data (I suspect so, because I HAVE read Excel files that contain more than 1 worksheet). When I deleted that second sheet, it worked. No changes to classpath needed.

Answer (score 0):

org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: Element themeManager@http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main is not a valid workbook@http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main document or a valid substitution.

**Solution** :- use .xlsx format instead of .xls

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I had to add this:

```
compile 'org.apache.poi:ooxml-schemas:1.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

For my case I had different versions of poi(s). poi-scratchpad was of 3.9 and all others - poi, poi-ooxml,poi-ooxml-schemas were of 3.12. I changed version of poi-scratchpad to 3.12 as well and everything started working.

Comment: As per [this Apache POI FAQ entry](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10204) that is entirely to be expected - [it is not supported to mix POI jars from different versions](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10204)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using maven for your project dependencies. You should have the following jars in your classpath
  [image]