# Cannot read Word Document content in Java

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jar, xwpf

I'm trying to load the content of a Word document (Word 2007 with file extension `.docx`) into a JTextArea (`txtLoadedText`). I'm using a `JFileChooser` to select the Word document but when I select the document I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/DocumentDocument$Factory

I tried looking at this Stackoverflow question ([How to avoid java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15106636/how-to-avoid-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror)), but it didn't make any difference.

How can I correct this?

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(chooser.getSelectedFile()));
XWPFWordExtractor extract = new XWPFWordExtractor(doc);
txtLoadedText.setText(extract.getText());
```

The jar files I have in place are:

```
poi-ooxml-3.8jar
xmlbeans.jar
poi-scratchpad-3.9.jar
poi-3.9.jar
dom4j.jar
poi-ooxml-3.7-20101029.jar
stax-api-1.0.1.jar
xbean.jar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try add `poi-ooxml-schemas.jar` to your projekt

Comment: Thank you that fixed it! :D