# Creating Word File With JTextPane Style Option

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I want to save the contents of a JTextPane to a word file. 
I don't have a problem saving but I can't currently keep some style options such as paragraph styles.

I use these libraries:

```
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;
```

Lines of code;

```
System.out.println("Kaydete basıldı");
        String text = textPane.getText();
        lblNewLabel.setText(text);

        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
        XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
        XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
        run.setText(text);

        try {

            FileOutputStream dosyaCikis = new FileOutputStream(
                    "sercan.docx");
            document.write(dosyaCikis);
            dosyaCikis.close();
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Apache POI or another way, it does not matter, I am waiting for your help.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Are you trying to simply copy text from a `JTextPane`, or style something in the Word document to look like a `JTextPane`?

Answer (score 1):

This example shows how to set various style options:(Apache POI)

[SimpleDocument](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/SimpleDocument.java)

Example code form the link:

```
   XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();
   XWPFParagraph p1 = doc.createParagraph();

        p1.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
        p1.setBorderBottom(Borders.DOUBLE);
        p1.setBorderTop(Borders.DOUBLE);    
        p1.setBorderRight(Borders.DOUBLE);
        p1.setBorderLeft(Borders.DOUBLE);
        p1.setBorderBetween(Borders.SINGLE);    
        p1.setVerticalAlignment(TextAlignment.TOP);

   XWPFRun r1 = p1.createRun();

        r1.setBold(true);
        r1.setText("The quick brown fox");
        r1.setBold(true);
        r1.setFontFamily("Courier");
        r1.setUnderline(UnderlinePatterns.DOT_DOT_DASH);
        r1.setTextPosition(100);
```

Other examples(styles,images .etc) can be found here:

[Example Package](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the options for writing Word files are limited from standard Java libraries.

You probably want to use a tool that explicitly supports Word formats - the best bet is probably LibreOffice, which is Free software. The [LibreOffice API](http://api.libreoffice.org) supports Java and other languages.

For a fuller explanation look here:

- [What's a good Java API for creating Word documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203174/whats-a-good-java-api-for-creating-word-documents)

However that answer refers to OpenOffice, of which LibreOffice is a more actively developed fork due to management issues over the years.

Comment: The OP mentioned he is using Apache POI, which works just fine.

Comment: Ah, right you are, I missed that. I obviously didn't read the question thoroughly albeit I'd suggest the imports could have been more obviously stated - excuses excuses! (EDIT: so I improved the question... the power of edits!)

Answer (score 0):

You could try [docx_editor_kit](http://java-sl.com/docx_editor_kit.html).  From the web page:

> it can open docx file and reflect the content in JEditorPane (or
>   JTextPane). Also user can create styled content and store the content
>   in docx format.

Somewhat related is my [docx4all](https://github.com/plutext/docx4all), but it hasn't been updated recently, and it may be overkill for your purposes.

Both of these use docx4j (as opposed to POI).