# How to edit MS Word documents using Java?

Tags: java, io, ms-word

I do have few Word templates, and my requirement is to replace some of the words/place holders in the document based on the user input, using Java. I tried lot of libraries including 2-3 versions of `docx4j` but nothing work well, they all just didn't do anything!

I know this question has been asked before, but I tried all options I know. So, using what java library I can "really" replace/edit these templates? My preference goes to the "easy to use / Few line of codes" type libraries.

I am using Java 8 and my MS Word templates are in MS Word 2007.

**Update**

This code is written by using the code sample provided by SO member `Joop Eggen`

```
public Main() throws URISyntaxException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException
    {
        URI docxUri = new URI("C:/Users/Yohan/Desktop/yohan.docx");
        Map<String, String> zipProperties = new HashMap<>();
        zipProperties.put("encoding", "UTF-8");

         FileSystem zipFS = FileSystems.newFileSystem(docxUri, zipProperties);

           Path documentXmlPath = zipFS.getPath("/word/document.xml");

            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document doc = builder.parse(Files.newInputStream(documentXmlPath));

            byte[] content = Files.readAllBytes(documentXmlPath);
            String xml = new String(content, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            //xml = xml.replace("#DATE#", "2014-09-24");
            xml = xml.replace("#NAME#", StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml("Sniper"));

            content = xml.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            Files.write(documentXmlPath, content);
    }
```

However this returns the below error

```
java.nio.file.ProviderNotFoundException: Provider "C" Not found

at: java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(FileSystems.java:341) at java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(FileSystems.java:341)

at java.nio.fileFileSystems.newFileSystem(FileSystems.java:276)
```

Comment: maybe for consideration (I would go for Apache HWPF): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203174/whats-a-good-java-api-for-creating-word-documents

Comment: @CsBalazsHungary: Link created 5 years ago. Java 8 was not there at that time.

Comment: Is MS Word 2007 already .docx? Because that format is perfect, you can use a java zip file system, and change /word/content.xml. The libraries do not guarantee the original format.

Comment: @Sniper sadly it indeed can cause problem :(

Comment: @JoopEggen: Yeah it is Docx. Prefer to see a library, you know, easy.

Comment: @JoopEggen: Is there any sample code?

Comment: The XML is readable too, load the DOM (or just text), replace the place holders and done. But I may be too naive w.r.t. the requirements. Rename .docx into .zip and take a look. I'll provide some sample code after a moment.

Comment: I've never done anything with Word, but I once used Apache POI for Excel and it worked pretty well, for both .xls and .xlsx: http://poi.apache.org/

Answer (score 4):

One may use for docx (a zip with XML and other files) a java zip file system and XML or text processing.

```
URI docxUri = ,,, // "jar:file:/C:/... .docx"
Map<String, String> zipProperties = new HashMap<>();
zipProperties.put("encoding", "UTF-8");
try (FileSystem zipFS = FileSystems.newFileSystem(docxUri, zipProperties)) {
    Path documentXmlPath = zipFS.getPath("/word/document.xml");
```

When using XML:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

    Document doc = builder.parse(Files.newInputStream(documentXmlPath));
    //Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
```

You can then use XPath to find the places, and write the XML back again.

It even might be that you do not need XML but could replace place holders:

```
    byte[] content = Files.readAllBytes(documentXmlPath);
    String xml = new String(content, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    xml = xml.replace("#DATE#", "2014-09-24");
    xml = xml.replace("#NAME#", StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml("Sniper")));
    ...
    content = xml.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    Files.delete(documentXmlPath);
    Files.write(documentXmlPath, content);
```

For a fast development, rename a copy of the .docx to a name with the .zip file extension, and inspect the files.

`File.write` should already apply StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING, but I have added `Files.delete` as some error occured. See comments.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You mean change the extension of my docx into .zip ?

Comment: hmm.. Can this work with word docx including images and tables?

Comment: You seems to be a great person, I will test and get back to you.

Comment: The images are in /media. And no, not so great, experience comes to everyone, now to you. The smart thing here, is not using java's ZipFile but the java FileSystem from "jar:file:" URIs. Then one can copy an image file into the docx with just `Files.copy` etc.

Comment: `The images are in /media` what did you mean? I have images and tables in my template. I don't want to touch any of them via Java, just wanted to know whether your example can read the file, replace the "text" and write back as it was; which means, without destroying the images, tables which were in the document, but of course with the replaced text.

Comment: Yes, the (zip) file xxx.docx remains unchanged; I thought you wanted to exchange images too. The fact that everything remains as-is, is the advantage of this approach. And XML is text, not using file positions. Hence not much can go wrong.

Comment: I am having a problem with `Document doc = builder.parse(Files.newInputStream(documentXmlPath));` from where you imported this?

Comment: `org.w3c.Document`, and `Files` is Java 7 SE. Maybe first try not the XML but the text-only version; that code is complete.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question with your answer. However it returned `java.nio.file.ProviderNotFoundException`

Comment: `URI docxUri = new URI("jar:file:/C:/Users/Yohan/Desktop/yohan.docx");` Without the protocol it searched for a "C:" protocol. It is a `File.toURI()` but with "jar:" in front.

Comment: Thanks. Now it says `java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: word/document.xml`

Comment: Added Files.delete; strange that write does not replace the file.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work. Nothing is replaced :(

Comment: It worked with me (delete was needed(. One must have MSWord closed of course.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/). `POI` can work with `doc` and `docx`, but `docx` is more documented therefore support of it better.

**UPD**: You can use [XDocReport](https://code.google.com/p/xdocreport/), which use POI. Also I recomend to use `xlsx` for templates because it more suitable and [more documented](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html)

Comment: Can you provide a link to an example please?

Comment: 1) in due time enough samples from distro, read sources (POI and XDocReport) and googling.

Answer (score 2):

I have spent a few days on this issue, until I found that what makes the difference is the `try-with-resources` on the FileSystem instance, appearing in Joop Eggen's snippet but not in question snippet:
`try (FileSystem zipFS = FileSystems.newFileSystem(docxUri, zipProperties))` 
Without such `try-with-resources` block, the `FileSystem` resource will not be closed (as explained in [Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)), and the word document not modified.

Answer (score 0):

Stepping back a bit, there are about 4 different approaches for editing words/placeholders:

- [MERGEFIELD](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/FieldsMailMerge.java) or DOCPROPERTY fields (if you are having problems with this in docx4j, then you have probably not set up your input docx correctly)
- [content control databinding](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/ContentControlsMergeXML.java)
- variable replacement on the document surface (either at the DOM/SAX level, or using a library)
- do stuff as XHTML, then [import that](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML/blob/master/src/samples/java/org/docx4j/samples/ConvertInXHTMLFragment.java)

Before choosing one, you should decide whether you also need to be able to handle:

- repeating data (eg adding table rows)
- conditional content (eg entire paragraphs which will either be present or absent)
- adding images

If you need these, then MERGEFIELD or DOCPROPERTY fields are probably out (though you can also use IF fields, if you can find a library which supports them).  And adding images makes DOM/SAX manipulation as advocated in one of the other answers, messier and error prone.

The other things to consider are:

- your authors: how technical are they? What does that imply for the authoring UI?
- the "user input" you mention for variable replacement, is this given, or is obtaining it part of the problem you are solving?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this to edit or replace the word in document

```
public class UpdateDocument {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        UpdateDocument obj = new UpdateDocument();

        obj.updateDocument(
                  "c:\\test\\template.docx",
                  "c:\\test\\output.docx",
                  "Piyush");
    }

    private void updateDocument(String input, String output, String name)
        throws IOException {

        try (XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(
                Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(input)))
        ) {

            List<XWPFParagraph> xwpfParagraphList = doc.getParagraphs();
            //Iterate over paragraph list and check for the replaceable text in each paragraph
            for (XWPFParagraph xwpfParagraph : xwpfParagraphList) {
                for (XWPFRun xwpfRun : xwpfParagraph.getRuns()) {
                    String docText = xwpfRun.getText(0);
                    //replacement and setting position
                    docText = docText.replace("${name}", name);
                    xwpfRun.setText(docText, 0);
                }
            }

            // save the docs
            try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(output)) {
                doc.write(out);
            }

        }

    }

}
```