# Create ZipFileSystem from a docx file obtained as a byte array without writing to a File

Tags: java, filesystems, uri, nio, docx

I want to modify **a docx document - obtained as a byte array** - by changing the word/document.xml using a `java nio ZipFileSystem`.
I have the following code (based on SO discussion [How to edit MS Word documents using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015943/how-to-edit-ms-word-documents-using-java/37136907#37136907)):

```
public static void modifyDocxContent(byte[] docx, byte[] newContent)  {
    try {
        // Create a Word File from byte[]
        File docxFile = new File("C:\\test\\simple.docx");
        Path docxPath = docxFile.toPath();
        Files.write(docxPath, docx);

        // Create jar URI for the same Word file
        URI docxUri = URI.create("jar:file:/C:/test/simple.docx");  

        // Create a zip FileSystem for word file and modify content in it
        Map<String, String> zipProperties = new HashMap<>();
        zipProperties.put("encoding", "UTF-8");
        zipProperties.put("create", "false");   

        try (FileSystem zipFS = FileSystems.newFileSystem(docxUri, zipProperties)) {
            Path documentXmlPath = zipFS.getPath("word", "document.xml");
            Files.delete(documentXmlPath);
            Files.write(documentXmlPath, newContent, StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING, StandardOpenOption.SYNC);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

I would like to avoid the File creation and writing to disk, needed in order to obtain the URI used in `newFileSystem` call. Is there a more efficient way you could think of for getting such nio ZipFileSystem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**
Use an in memory file system such as Google [jimfs](https://github.com/google/jimfs) or [marshall](https://github.com/marschall/memoryfilesystem).
Code snippet similar to the one in  [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37603205/jimfs-not-recognized-by-zipfilesystemprovider)