# Create Word file (docx) on Android with Jword Library Apache POI (Solution)

Tags: android, ms-office, apache-poi, .doc

Create Word document on Android with JWord

JWord is an API compatible with Microsoft Word for Java and Android. The API allows you to easily create, read, modify and analyze Word documents without using Microsoft Word.

In the following source code it shows in a practical way how to generate a Word file (.docx) efficiently. This library contains a variety of features that can be implemented in your document according to the need you have.

The official site of the bookstore is Independentsoft
http://www.independentsoft.com/jword/

From this site you can download the evaluation version for 30 days or get in touch with support to acquire the full version; In the same way you can contact me to support you in this process.

Install from Google Play here https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.helpmybusinesspos.generatewordfile

Check the video here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5OIgmK7otr0

Source code here http://myandroidpos.helpmybusinesspos.info/crear-documento-word-en-android-con-jword/

WhatasApp: +52 5545404329

Comment: You can see the following solution youtube.com/watch?v=5OIgmK7otr0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a beginner you can start with some tutorials :

1. http://poi.apache.org/poifs/how-to.html
2. http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/android-read-write-excel-file-using.html
3. http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/Creating-new-word-doc-with-POI-td2289680.html
4. http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/comment-page-1/

StackOverflow link

1. [What's a good Java API for creating Word documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203174/whats-a-good-java-api-for-creating-word-documents)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so bro, but i finally use JWord, and it's good for create word files. This is the site http://www.independentsoft.com/jword/, but need to buy it and is expensive :|

Comment: You can see the following solution https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5OIgmK7otr0

Comment: Thank so much...