# Design documentation api java

Tags: java, kotlin

I need to write application that will be generate Design documentation with my template as MS Word document. For now I tried to use JasperReports and apache api, how ever I didn't find any way to create templates. Is there any other api to create desgin documentation? Or maybe I missed anything in api's I wrote?

Here is an example of my document I want to get: https://pastenow.ru/55FFI

Also the example of the full document: https://www.dropbox.com/s/s174ydv77cvvjr0/document.doc?dl=0

Comment: MS Word seems to be the worst choice for API documentation ... what about markdown, asciidoc, html?

Comment: It's a standart documentation so I afraid but it must be word or pdf

Comment: Use markdown or asciidoc to generate pdfs, pandoc is a good starting point.

Comment: Much better. @JFMeier is right. So I used http://www.doxygen.nl/index.html for the general public api or internal api, but I also provide design documents, but we wrote our own template from scratching using Microsoft word, then dump to a view for the doxygen pages.

Comment: @JFMeier the main problem for me to create custom running title. Can I did it there?

Comment: @Y2Kot You could program your entire solution [SO- With similar discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203174/is-there-a-java-api-that-can-create-rich-word-documents)

Comment: https://docbook.org/ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DocBook (Check simplified docbook, as that uses simpler tags). The advantage is in having a kind of templates at the end and the XML integration. Costs time at the beginning. And I had to struggle to have some things my way.

Comment: @JFMeier it's not an api doc. I need an api to create doc files with running title as in my examples.